# Copy range up to delimiter

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator

The problem I was trying to solve sounded pretty basic, but turned out to be a bit hairy.

I need to select some lines of arbitrary length from an input stream (file or standard input) and print them to output. In other words, a function that just echos the line would do the job. The input stream is encoded in UTF-8. For reasons that I don't quite understand, the normal `<string>` mangles the stream, so I couldn't use:

```
std::string line;
std::readline(line);
std::cout << line;
```

I did solve it using [`basic_istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline); however, this function writes to a buffer, and I need to tell it how big the buffer is. To make it deal with lines of arbitrary length, I need to read to a buffer in a loop, checking whether `failbit` is set (when the end of the line wasn't reached).

Then, the easier solution was to use iterators on the input and the output stream, like this:

```
template<typename I, typename O, typename T>
I copy_until(I first, I last, O d_first, T delim)
{
    while (first != last && *first != delim) {
        *d_first = *first;
        ++first;
        ++d_first;
    }
    return first;
}
```

This copies from `first` up to `last` at most, and stops if the delimiter is encountered. It returns a pointer to the first character in the input range that was not copied.

It can be used like this to copy all input to output:

```
int main()
{
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> first(std::cin);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> last;
    std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> d_first(std::cout);

    while (first != last) {
        first = copy_until(first, last, d_first, '\n');
        std::cout.put(*first);
        ++first;
    }
}
```

The third argument of `copy_until` could of course be a unary predicate, then instead of `while (first != last && *first != delim)` it would say `while (first != last && !p(*first))`.

More important questions:

- Is there an algorithm in `<algorithm>` that I have overlooked? `copy_if` and `partition_point` come close, but they don't do exactly that, and `partition_point` followed by `copy_n` will not work with forward iterators.
- I am not sure how to declare that the two iterators need to point to the same type as the type of the delimiter or the argument to the unary predicate.
- Not certain about the return value. This one is the most useful for my particular use case.
- Or maybe there is a much, much easier way that avoids this altogether. But `copy_until` might be useful in other contexts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<typename I, typename O, typename T>
I copy_until(I first, I last, O d_first, T delim) {
```

- Make your interfaces explicit.  While `I` and `O` simply translate to iterator direction, what category type is your function requiring?  Use the interface to document concepts (e.g. `InputIterator`, `OutputIterator`).
- Declare read-only input parameters that are expensive or of an unknown type (`T`) by `const&`.

---

> Not certain about the return value. This one is the most useful for my particular use case.

- When determining your functions return specification, consider what useful information the caller may want.  You return `first` because the function may not consume the entire range.  It is important to know where `copy_until` ended so it may be restarted.  How about `d_first`?  Knowing where to resume copying seems like something a caller would also want.

---

> I am not sure how to declare that the two iterators need to point to the same type as the type of the delimiter or the argument to the unary predicate.
>
> Or maybe there is a much, much easier way that avoids this altogether. But copy_until might be useful in other contexts?

Why not both? Having a `copy_while` function that takes a predicate would be useful.  `boost::copy_until` takes a predicate and is just a negated version of their `boost::copy_while`.  See [boost/algorithm/cxx11/copy_if.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/algorithm/cxx11/copy_if.hpp).

---

> - Is there an algorithm in `<algorithm>` that I have overlooked? `copy_if` and partition_point come close, but they don't do exactly that, and `partition_point` followed by `copy_n` will not work with forward iterators.

To meet the requirements of input iterators, you are not going to be able to improve on what you already have.  If you want to optimize for other cases, you can refer to the notes on [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

> **Notes**
>
> In practice, implementations of std::copy avoid multiple assignments and use bulk copy functions such as `std::memmove` if the value type is `TriviallyCopyable`.

So, if you have `TriviallyCopyable` types and are working with contiguous areas of memory, something as simple as a `std::find` and a call to `std::copy` can offer speed-up.

You would end up with something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>

namespace detail {
struct StandardVersion {};
struct OptimizedVersion {};

template <typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename T>
auto copy_until(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator out,
                const T& stop_value, StandardVersion)
    -> std::tuple<InputIterator, OutputIterator> {
  while (bool(first != last) && bool(*first != stop_value)) {
    *out++ = *first++;
  }

  return std::make_tuple(first, out);
}

template <typename ContigousIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename T>
auto copy_until(ContigousIterator first, ContigousIterator last,
                OutputIterator out, const T& stop_value, OptimizedVersion)
    -> std::tuple<ContigousIterator, OutputIterator> {
  const auto stop_iter = std::find(first, last, stop_value);
  return std::make_tuple(stop_iter, std::copy(first, stop_iter, out));
}
};

template <typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename T>
inline auto copy_until(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                       OutputIterator out, const T& stop_value) {
  using InputValueType =
      typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type;
  using OutputValueType =
      typename std::iterator_traits<OutputIterator>::value_type;
  using InputCategory =
      typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::iterator_category;
  using OutputCategory =
      typename std::iterator_traits<OutputIterator>::iterator_category;

  return detail::copy_until(
      first, last, out, stop_value,
      std::conditional_t<
         std::is_trivially_copyable<InputValueType>::value
         && std::is_base_of<std::random_access_iterator_tag, InputCategory>::value
         && std::is_base_of<std::random_access_iterator_tag, OutputCategory>::value,
         detail::OptimizedVersion, 
         detail::StandardVersion>{});
}
```

Note: While the concept of `ContiguousIterator` is being added to the standard in C++17, a `std::contiguous_iterator_tag` isn't being added.  Dispatching on `std::random_access_iterator_tag` will use the optimized call to the contiguous operations of `std::copy` for all random access containers except `std::deque`.  `std::deque` is not guaranteed to be contiguous and would fall back to copying by element.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. When I finally read the documentation of `std::basic_istream::get()` carefully enough, I discovered that I can copy a line from an input stream `in` to the buffer of an output stream `out` by simply calling `in.get(*out.rdbuf())` (wrote it up as an answer, for posterity). It is that simple. A good exercise anyway, and I definitely learned a lot from your answer.

Answer (score 5):

> The third argument of copy_until could of course be a unary predicate, then instead of `while (first != last && *first != delim)` it would say `while (first != last && !p(*first))`.

Even better: remove the `I last` argument entirely! Just use the predicate for the whole thing, and the condition becomes `while (!p(first))`.

---

You're returning `I` (the place you stopped parsing the input stream), but similar functions in the STL return `O` (the place they stopped outputting to the output stream). The latter is more useful in STL cases, because typically the caller *knows* where he stopped parsing the input: it's `last`!

In your case, both `I` and `O` are useful; so why not return both?

```
template<typename I, typename O, typename Pred>
std::pair<I, O> copy_until(I first, O d_first, Pred pred)
{
    while (!pred(first)) {
        *d_first = *first;
        ++first;
        ++d_first;
    }
    return {first, d_first};
}
```

Your `main` thus becomes:

```
int main()
{
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> first(std::cin);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> last;
    std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> d_first(std::cout);

    while (first != last) {
        std::tie(first, std::ignore) = copy_until(
            first, d_first, [=](auto it){ return it == last || *it == '\n'; }
        );
        if (first == last) break;  // Whoops!
        std::cout.put(*first);
        ++first;
    }
}
```

The `// Whoops!` comment indicates the fix for a crashing bug in your original `main`.

---

Boost.Algorithm actually has both `copy_until` and its inverse, `copy_while`: http://marshall.calepin.co/copy_while.html
Strangely, Boost's version takes `last` as a parameter exactly the way yours does. In Boost's case, I think that might be because they're trying to target C++03, which doesn't have lambdas, so there's no way that's both easy and lightweight to express `[last](auto it) { return it != last && *it != delim; }` — in C++03 you had to do that with `boost::bind` and maybe `boost::function` as well.

---

> I am not sure how to declare that the two iterators need to point to the same type as the type of the delimiter or the argument to the unary predicate.

The short answer is "don't"; complicated dependencies like that usually indicate that you've put the abstraction boundary in the wrong place (e.g. in this example, passing `First, Last, Delim` instead of `First, Pred`). But just for the record, you could do something crazy with `enable_if`, which can go on the return type of the function or on one of its parameters or on one of its template parameters, your choice.

```
auto copy_until(I first, I last, O d_first, T delim)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(*first), T>, I>
{
    // ...
}
```

I'm pretty sure you *don't* want to assert that `decltype(*d_first)` is `T`, because that would prevent you from using something like a `back_insert_iterator<vector<T>>` with this algorithm.

Comment: The delimiter could also just be `std::iterator_traits<I>::reference`, so that it is the same type as used by the input iterator.

Comment: Oops! Thanks @Edward: it's fixed now. My intention was to get rid of the `last` parameter, but I guess I never finished that cut-and-paste job.

Comment: It's a very minor style difference, but in my version the contents of the loop is simply `*d_first++ = *first++;`.  I find that form shorter and easier to read and understand, but not everyone does.

Comment: What if you never find your delimiter (say, you get to end-of-file without seeing a newline)? You absolutely need the end of the range. Or am I misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: @Edward It really doesn't hurt to put it separately. The problem with any post-increment in C++ is that it needs to make a copy of the thing being incremented (this at least is my understanding), and in the case of complex user-defined types this can be too expensive.

Comment: @Boris: First, I agree that there should be a `last` and there should be a check for it.  Second, it's true that it doesn't hurt to put the increments separately, but remember that what is being incremented is the *iterator*, rather than the contained item.  My compiler generates the same code either way.

Comment: @Boris: I've updated again with your example `main` function to show the intended usage. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Boris @Edward: I would agree with Edward for business logic, and with Boris for library-level stuff. If you can be reasonably certain that `it++` is cheap for your particular uses, and/or you can go adjust the implementation of `copy_while` when your guess turns out to be wrong, then `*it++` is definitely easier to read. If you're going to bury your code in a library and ship it to the world, so you need 100% foolproofness for all possible `it`s, then `++it` is safest.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers were great (a pity I can't accept both). I need to add the "much easier way" answer. Since this was about copying (unformatted) new-line separated line from input to output, the simple function that does that would be:

```
template<typename InputStream, typename OutputStream>
void copy_line(InputStream& in, OutputStream& out)
{
    char c = in.get();
    while (in && c != '\n') {
        out.put(c);
        c = in.get();
    }
/* Or why not even:
    for (char c = in.get(); in && c != '\n'; c = in.get())
        out.put(c);
*/
}
```

This is almost identical in semantics to the `copy_until()` discussed above; it consumes the new line char, however, since this is more useful for my very specific use case.

All the recommendations in the other answers about return value, arguments, names and so on apply here too.

### However

while reading I finally found that I have missed the obvious, namely, `std::basic_istream::get()` can directly read into a stream buffer...

```
template<typename InputStream, typename OutputStream>
void copy_line(InputStream& in, OutputStream& out)
{
    in.get(*out.rdbuf());
    in.ignore();
}
```

The `ignore()` is there because the delimiter is left on the input stream.